# Deploying Django 1.5 app on GAE SDK 1.8.1

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been trying to deploy my application on GAE for 2 days, but I have not been successful.
    I am using Python 2.7, Django 1.5 and Google App Engine SDK 1.8.1 and the application is running appropriately is localhost.
    To deploy my application, I have followed the instructions at [1] with just one difference: I have changed the 
    `ROOT_URLCONF = 'tcn_project.urls'` to `ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'` (where tcn_project is the name of my project).
    The current error is (where cc_simulator is the name of my application):

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~cc-simulator/1.368666896883800783/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
from cc_simulator import views
ImportError: No module named cc_simulator
```

Comment: What is [1] that you are referring to for instructions?

Comment: Sorry, here is the reference: 
[1]: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django
Thank you!

Comment: why is there that weird number if your path?